# AlertDialogを出したいが、ビルドエラーになってしまう。

Tags: java, android, kotlin

#### 発生している問題

AlertDialogを出したいのですが、ビルドエラーになってしまいます。
調べてみましたが、わからないので教えて下さい。

> val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

ここでエラーメッセージが出てます。

---

#### エラーメッセージ

```
Error:(195, 45) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public constructor Builder(context: android.content.Context!) defined in android.app.AlertDialog.Builder
public constructor Builder(context: android.content.Context!, theme: kotlin.Int) defined in android.app.AlertDialog.Builder
```

### 該当のソースコード

```
package jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.activities

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.SearchRecentSuggestions
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.widget.Toast
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.R
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.UserLogoutActivity
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.advertising.AdvertisingIdentifierManager
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.constants.Constants
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.data.feed.user.User
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.fragment.WebFragment
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.proguardHelper.NonObfuscate
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.suggestionsProvider.SuggestionsProvider
import jp.yahuu.hogehoge.app.web.*
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        //履歴消去選んだ場合
        private fun showLogoutDialog() {

            // AlertDialog.Builderオブジェクト生成

            val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

            dialogBuilder.setTitle("検索履歴を削除します")
            dialogBuilder.setMessage("操作は取り消すことができません。よろしいですか？")

            val self = this

            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("削除", object: DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int) {

//                    val suggestions = SearchRecentSuggestions(
//                            self,
//                            SuggestionsProvider.Authority,
//                            SuggestionsProvider.Mode
//                    )
//
//                    suggestions.clearHistory()
//
//                    Toast.makeText(self, "検索履歴を削除しました", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }

            })

            dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("キャンセル", object: DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int) {

                    dialog.cancel()

                }

            })

            dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)
            dialogBuilder.create().show()

        }
```

Comment: `this` ではなく、activity 名を付けるとどうなりますか？ `AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivitiyName.this)`

Comment: 出来ました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`this` ではなく、以下の形式で activity 名を付けてみてください。

**変更前:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

**変更後:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder(yourActivitiyName.this)
```

---

*この投稿は @user9156 さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*